# Задача суммирования чисел в списке на Python

Tags: python, циклы, списки, python-3.6

Задание:
написать программу, на вход которой подаётся список чисел одной строкой. Программа должна для каждого элемента этого списка вывести сумму двух его соседей. Для элементов списка, являющихся крайними, одним из соседей считается элемент, находящий на противоположном конце этого списка. Например, если на вход подаётся список "1 3 5 6 10", то на выход ожидается список "13 6 9 15 7" (без кавычек).
Если на вход пришло только одно число, надо вывести его же.
Вывод должен содержать одну строку с числами нового списка, разделёнными пробелом.
Мой код:

```
num = input().split()
result = 0
numlen = len(num)
final_result = ""
space = " "
f = 1
for i in num:
  if numlen == 1:
    print(i)
  elif i == num[0]:
    result = int(num[1]) + int(num[numlen - 1])
    final_result += str(result) + space
    result = 0
  elif i == num[numlen - 1]:
    result = int(num[numlen - 2]) + int(num[0])
    final_result += str(result)
    result = 0
  else:
    result = int(num[f+1]) + int(num[f-1])
    final_result += str(result) + space
    result = 0
    f +=1
print(final_result)
```

С числами по порядку, в реверс, с отрицательными и единичным - все работает правильно, но если на вход дать "1 10 2 10 3 10", то начинается неразбериха. Помогите найти причину.

Comment: Это задача случаем не из курса степик? Вроде бы там я ее видел :)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте:

```
l = [int(n) for n in input().split()]
s = len(l)
if s == 1:
    print(l[0])
else:
    r = []
    
    for i in range(s):
        li = s - 1 if i == 0 else i - 1
        ri = 0 if i == s - 1 else i + 1
        r.append(l[li] + l[ri])

    print(' '.join(str(n) for n in r))
```